# Pointer arithmetic result in pointer to another struct member via previous member address (in the same struct)

Tags: c, pointers, language-lawyer

What is the view from C standard about pointer arithmetic result in pointer to another struct member via previous member address in the same struct?

---

### Code 1 (without struct), mystery_1

```c
int mystery_1(void)
{
    int one = 1, two = 2;
    int *p1 = &one + 1;
    int *p2 = &two;
    unsigned long i1 = (unsigned long) p1;
    unsigned long i2 = (unsigned long) p2;

    if (i1 == i2)
        return p1 == p2;
    return 2;
}
```

From code 1, I know that the result is not determined, because there is no guarantee how local variables on the stack lay.

What if I use struct like this (code 2)?

---

### Code 2 (with struct), mystery_2

```
int mystery_2(void)
{
    struct { int one, two; } my_var = {
        .one = 1, .two = 2
    };
    int *p1 = &my_var.one + 1;
    int *p2 = &my_var.two;
    unsigned long i1 = (unsigned long) p1;
    unsigned long i2 = (unsigned long) p2;
    
    if (i1 == i2)
        return p1 == p2;
    return 2;
}
```

---

### Compilers Output

Godbolt link: https://godbolt.org/z/jGoKfETn7

#### GCC 10.2

```
mystery_1:
        xorl    %eax, %eax # return 0, while clang returns 2 (fine as no guarantee)
        ret
mystery_2:
        movl    $1, %eax # return 1, as compiler must consider the memory order of struct members
        ret
```

#### Clang 11.0.1

```
mystery_1:                              # @mystery_1
        movl    $2, %eax # return 2, while gcc returns 0 (fine as no guarantee)
        retq
mystery_2:                              # @mystery_2
        movl    $1, %eax # return 1, as compiler must consider the memory order of struct members
        retq
```

---

### My understanding

- In code 1, the return value is not determined, because there is no guarantee about memory layout of local variables on the stack.
- In code 2, the return value is determined and well-defined as `1` as `p1 == p2` yields true, because struct guarantees the memory layout. So next address of `my_var.one` is `my_var.two`, and compiler is not allowed to assume that `p1` and `p2` is different because of their provenance.

### Questions

- Is my understanding correct?
- According to C standard, does `mystery_2` always return 1 as `p1 == p2` yields true?
- In `mystery_2`, is compiler allowed to assume that `p1 != p2`, so the function returns 0?

### The problem

I had a discussion with someone regarding the struct case (`mystery_2`), they said that:

`p1` points to (one past) one, and `p2` points to two. Those are, in C spec, counted as different "objects". The spec then goes on to define that pointers to different objects might compare as different, even though both pointers have the exact same bit pattern

Comment: No, I don't think this is guaranteed. The compiler can put padding in between the members, etc.

Comment: @cigien no, that does not answer my question.

Comment: @cigien they both are int (the same size), why should compiler give padding between members?

Comment: @AmmarFaizi Why shouldn't it?

Comment: What a compiler might or might not do is completely irrelevant. You tagged this as [language-lawyer] which means you want to know what the language guarantees. The language allows the compiler to add padding, and so the behavior is not guaranteed.

Comment: @AndrewHenle I think padding is required if the offset is not multiple of the sizeof that member. So if they both are int (assuming 4 bytes, there should not be a padding between them).

Comment: @cigien yeah, but padding is supposed to make the offset be multiple of that member, in this case there should not be a padding.

Comment: You appear to have a misunderstanding of what the language standard means. The Standard simply puts requirements on the behavior of a compiler. Beyond those requirements, a compiler can do anything it wants and still conform to the Standard. e.g. if the Standard doesn't impose requirements on padding, a compiler could insert 1GB of padding between ints and be conforming. Whether the compiler *would* do that is irrelevant.

Comment: @AmmarFaizi  What you think "should" be does not place restrictions on the compiler.

Comment: @AndrewHenle in the above struct, is compiler allowed to assume that `p1` is not `p2` when it optimizes the code?

Comment: Honestly, I had a discussion with someone, they said that: `p1` points to (one past) one, and `p2` points to two. Those are, in C spec, counted as different "objects". So the compiler is allowed to assume that `p1 != p2`.

Comment: Look at this: https://ideone.com/HvkmZi

I don't understand what the hell is going on here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two basics of pointer arithmetic are, per C 2018 6.5.6 8:

- A pointer to an element of an array may be adjusted (by addition and subtraction of an integer) to point to any element of the array or to the end (one beyond the last element). Arithmetic outside that is not defined by the C standard.
- For pointer arithmetic, a single object acts like an array of one object.

Therefore `int *p1 = &one + 1;` has defined behavior.

Regarding:

```
    unsigned long i1 = (unsigned long) p1;
    unsigned long i2 = (unsigned long) p2;
```

Since it is not the focus of this question, let’s assume the implementation-defined conversion of a pointer to an `unsigned long` produces a unique value that uniquely identifies the pointer value. (That is, conversion of any address to an `unsigned long` only ever produces one value for that address, and conversion of the value back to a pointer reproduces the address. The C standard does not guarantee this.)

Then, if `i1 == i2`, it implies `p1 == p2` and vice-versa. Per C 2018 6.5.9 6,`p1` and `p2` can compare equal only if `two` (which `p2` points to) has been laid out in memory one beyond `one` (which `p1` points just beyond). (In general, pointers can compare equal for other reasons, but those cases involve pointers to the same object, a structure and its first member, the same function, and so on, all of which are ruled out for this particular `p1` and `p2`.)

So the code in Code 1 will return 1 if `two` is laid out in memory just after `one` and 2 otherwise.

The same is true in Code 2. The pointer arithmetic `&my_var.one + 1` is defined, and the resulting `p1` compares equal to `p2` if and only if the member `two` immediately follows the member `one` in memory.

However, `two` does not have to immediately follow `one`. This statement is incorrect:

> … struct guarantees the memory layout.

The C standard allows implementations to put padding between structure members. Common C implementations will not do this for `struct { int one, two; }` because it is not needed for alignment (once `one` is aligned, the address immediately following it is also suitably aligned for `int`, so no padding is needed), but C standard does not guarantee it.

### Notes

`uintptr_t`, declared in `<stdint.h>`, is a better choice for converting pointers to integers. However, the standard only guarantees that `(uintptr_t) px == (uintptr_t) py` implies `px == py`, not that `px == py` implies `(uintptr_t) px == (uintptr_t) py`. In other words, converting two pointers to the same object to `uintptr_t` might produce two different values, although converting them back to pointers will result in pointers that compare as equal.

Answer (score 1):

> Is my understanding correct?

No.

You're correct about the local variables; but not for the struct example.

> According to C standard, does mystery_2 always return 1 as p1 == p2 yields true?

No. That's not guaranteed by the C standard. Because there can be padding between `one` and `two`.

Practically, there's no reason for any compiler to insert padding between them in *this* example.
And you can nearly always expect `mystery_2` to return 1. But this is not required by the C standard and thus a pathological compiler could insert padding between `one` and `two` and that'd be perfectly valid.

With respect to padding: The only guarantee is that there can't be any padding before the first member of a struct. So a pointer to a struct and a pointer to its first member are guaranteed to be the same. No other guarantees whatsoever.

Note: you should be using `uinptr_t` for storing pointer values (`unsigned long` isn't guaranteed to be able to hold a pointer value).